# 500 internal server error in FPDI in line $pdf = new Fpdi();

Tags: php, apache, fpdf, internal-server-error, fpdi

When I use this code I get always 500 server internal error when loads line
$pdf = new Fpdi();
All libraries are ok and paths are ok....
I've download for different sites and nothing...

Thanks for your help !!!!

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

require_once('js/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('js/fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('IPE.pdf');
$pageId = $pdf->importPage(1, PdfReader\PageBoundaries::MEDIA_BOX);

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useImportedPage($pageId, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output('I', 'generated.pdf');
```

?>

Comment: You can see this in :
http://app.guvavet.com/testfpdi2.php

Comment: The first thing you always need to do, when you get a 500, is go and _check the server’s error log_!

Comment: For sure you need to check your error logs as @CBroe told you. I guess you are on a PHP version < 5.6. Couldy that be the case?

Comment: Thanks CBroe and Jan for you help !

PHP Version is 7.3
Error log is empty of any error of this... 

Any idea?